# Single hole water faucet

Tags: plumbing, water, kitchens, faucet

I was wondering if one can put the lever on a single hole faucet in the front instead of the left. That way the hot is on the left and cold on the right. My daughter thinks  I am crazy but I think it is a personal preference. Any thought or comments or has anyone put the lever in the front. Thanks!

Comment: pictures?   you can put it where ever you want really

Comment: This really needs more details on what you're asking. My kitchen faucet is a single hole unit (with a handy base plate to cover the other two holes that were already existing). I move the lever left for hot and right for cold, up for more flow, down for less (until it's off). Not sure what you're asking.

Comment: Why not just swap hot and cold lines to the faucet? Or maybe I am not understanding the question.

Answer (score 0):

Almost certainly you can, but you may be splashed when operating the lever.

Many showers are like this, it's not always a disadvantage :)